# React.js + Immutable.js: best practices for shouldComponentUpdate with filtered lists

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

What are the best practices for filtering a `Immutable.List` for passing down to child components as regards to `shouldComponentUpdate`?

Illustrative example: I'm building a calendar. It has a `<Week>` component, holding seven `<Day>` components. The `<Week>` receives a list of all calendar events, then renders the `<Day>`s and passes a filtered subset of events to each of them as props.

All the `<Day>` components have `PureRenderMixin` attached to them, with the intent of preventing useless re-renders. But, given that `Immutable.List.filter` returns a new object each time, when a single event is added, every `<Day>` component will receive a 'new' event list as prop and re-render, even when all but one of them have the same content.

My current idea is writing a custom `shouldComponentUpdate` that compares `hashCode`s of every list component decides to re-render based on that. Is there a better, more established way to do it?

Code example as requested. Assume `<Week>` is wired up to a flux store and gets the events from it.

```
Day = React.createClass({
  propTypes: { events: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.List) },

  mixins: [ React.addons.PureRenderMixin ],

  render: function(){
    const events = this.props.events.map((event) => {
      return <div key={event.get('id')}>{event.get('name')}</div>
    })

    return <div>{events}</div>
  }
})

Week = React.createClass({
  propTypes: { events: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.List) },

  mixins: [ React.addons.PureRenderMixin ],

  render: function(){
    const days = [1,2,3,4,5,6,0].map((weekday) => {
      const dayEvents = this.props.events.filter(event => event.get('weekday') === weekday)

      return <Day events={dayEvents} key={weekday} /> 
    })

    return <div>{days}</div>
  }
})
```

Comment: In `shouldComponentUpdate` you can compare Immutable objects with `===`, no need for hashcode comparison. From the docs: "Immutable always returns itself when a mutation results in an identical collection, allowing for using === equality to determine if something has changed."

Comment: Won't really help, because I'm creating new objects using `filter`. See https://jsfiddle.net/gouw5wvk/1/ - the content is the same, but `===` says they are different.

Comment: How are you using filter between the Week and Day components, can you add some code?

Comment: @HazardouS added a code example.

Answer (score 0):

You should restructure the model like this-

```
{'Monday':{...events...}, 'Tuesday':{...events...}, ...}
```

This way you can pass the right set of events to the right child Day component.

**Update**
Noticed you are using numbers for weekdays, simply substitute day names with numbers, or use a List/array to store events. Basically we are doing away with the need of calling `filter`.

Comment: The Week/Day example was just for illustration of the concept - the real case is far more complex. The end user can select how to sub-divide the data set, and each division can then be then sub-divided further based on user preference. Real use cases regularly involve five levels of slicing by different criteria. While it could be possible re-structure the data model to accommodate that, I feel it would greatly complicate updating the data and routing the new records that get received from server. I leave that as a last resort.